# How to limit input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small html contact form, which contains Name and Phone only.

What I'm trying to do is whenever `Key Up` event occurs I want to check which key was pressed, and for the `Phone` field I would accept only numbers. For the `Name` field, I would allow only alphabetic letters, not numbers.

For example, if I'm typing data into the `Phone` input, and I press on any character but a number, it should not show up in the input field.

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) You're hardly the first to ask this question.

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain what's not working.

Comment: Well, I have removed most of my tries, but generally, what I have tried is to determine which key was pressed and then check whether it's a number/alphabet. Couldn't do this.. I got stuck after checking the E value of the `Key Up` event because I'm getting a number as a result, and I don't know how to check which category it is related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" /><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#phone").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    }
});

$("#name").keyup(function() {
     if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
     }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/KfRxv/

Comment: This solution works, but the only thing that disturbs me, that it actually shows the number/alphabet before deleting it. I would like it not to show that number/alphabet. Is that possible?

Comment: Honestly I don't think so, the browser needs to know the key value before it can do anything about it and it is going to display the second it knows what it is.

Comment: I see. there is a slight problem. My language is Hebrew and if I type in the `Name` field my alphabet characters, it's deleting it. How do I also enable Hebrew?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just found out that I actually just add my own alphabet to the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For numeric characters only add the following javascript:

```
function checkInput(e)
{
  var k;
  document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
  var char = String.fromCharCode(k);
  if(!char.match(/^\d+$/))return false;

  return true;
}
```

Then in the markup for your input element add onkeypress="return checkInput(event)".

You can modify the JS to only allow whatever characters you want.

Comment: Works for numbers, but what If I press BackSpace? there is a problem with that :s

Comment: You could change the regex to (/[\d\b]/) to get both digits and backspace to be allowed. Really, you'll have the fiddle with the regex to make it fit whatever you want but the JS will stay the same. If you want to allow only alpha characters you'd change the regex for that, same if you only want to allow special characters, etc. The JS I provided is more of a framework than a copy-paste to your website.